# How to implement a Nginx rewrite rule with a space (%C2%A0) in the location?

Tags: nginx, vhosts

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to write this Nginx rule for rewriting the url 'http://example.com/test/%C2%A0' to 'http://example.com/test'.

What I have tried so far in my vhost:

```
Location http://example.com/test/%C2%A0 {
  rewrite ^/.* http://example.com/test permanent;
}
```

It doesn't seem to work, while I restarted the nginx service.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: in your server block try `rewrite ^/test/%C2%A0 http://example.com/test permanent;`

Answer (score 0):

The percent-encoded characters are decoded by the time that `location` or `rewrite` see them. But the non-breaking space still looks like two characters. The regular expression syntax can specify characters using their hex value, for example:

```
location ~ ^/test/\xc2\xa0$ {
    return 301 /test;
}
```

Or:

```
rewrite ^/test/\xc2\xa0$ /test permanent;
```

See [the `location` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) or [the `rewrite` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.